# String tokenization using StringTokenizer in android

Tags: android, json, string, stringtokenizer

I am trying to formate a string which has been received from a json into a new formate. The actual string is `[90.36855,23.750088333333334]` and my target is to convert it into two different strings like `90.36855` and `23.750088333333334`

I tried in the following way

```
String s = "[90.36855,23.750088333333334]";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "[");
String lat = st.nextToken();
String lon = st.nextToken();
```

But it shows `FATAL EXCEPTION: main`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here in this string `[` comes only once. So in this line `String lon = st.nextToken();` it wil throw you exception, as `nextToken()` is not available.

As the `String` is `JSONArray`, you can use `org.json` to get lat and lon.

E.g.:

```
String s = "[90.36855,23.750088333333334]";
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
String lat = jsonArray.get(0);
String lon = jsonArray.get(1);
```

But if you don't want to use `JSONArray` then `StringTokenizer` can also do the trick for you. Just update regx with `[],`:

```
String s = "[90.36855,23.750088333333334]";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "[],");
String lat = st.nextToken();
String lon = st.nextToken();
```

Comment: yes this really works. I am gonna use the first one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Though other answers are also correct, but I am going to accept this answer as I used jsonArray.get(0) to solve this problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
String s = "[90.36855,23.750088333333334]";
String result = s.replaceAll("[]","");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(result, ",");
String lat = st.nextToken();
String lon = st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with this,

```
    String s = "[90.36855,23.750088333333334]";
    s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1); //Trim first and last brackets
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ","); //pass comma as delimeter
    String lat = st.nextToken();
    String lon = st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String s = "[90.36855,23.750088333333334]";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
        String lat = st.nextToken().substring(1);
        String lon = st.nextToken();
        lon = lon.substring(0,lon.length()-1)
```